# Unable to perform Insert Operation from Android to Azure Mobile Service

Tags: android, azure-mobile-services

I am trying to perform insert operation from Android to Azure Mobile service without success. I am able to perform insert from the Web Try it out, but not from Android. I was able to perform the insert with the Todoitem object but not with my own.

Here is the database
[image]

And here is my Java Class

```
public class Bill {
    public String Id;
    public String UserId;
    public String BillName;
    public double BillAmount;
    public Date BillDueDate;
    public Boolean Paid;
}
```

And here is my Mobile Services Usage

```
MobileServiceTable<Bill> mBillTable = mClient.getTable("Bills", Bill.class);

    Bill mBill = new Bill();
    mBill.BillAmount = 33.50;
    mBill.UserId = "2";
    mBill.BillDueDate = new Date(System.currentTimeMillis());
    mBill.BillName = "Android Phone Bill";
    mBill.Paid = true;


   Log.i(TAG, "Calling Insert");
   mBillTable.insert(mBill, new TableOperationCallback<Bill>() {

        @Override
        public void onCompleted(Bill entity, Exception exception, ServiceFilterResponse response) {
            Log.i(TAG, "Called insert");
            if (exception == null){
                Log.i(TAG, "Azure insert succeeded ID: " + entity.Id);
            } else {
                Log.i(TAG, "Azure insert failed again " + exception);
            }
        }
    });
    return rootView;
```

No matter what I do, I get the following error

**Azure insert failed again
com.microsoft.windowsazure.mobileservices.MobileServiceException:
Error while processing request.**

What I am I doing wrong?  For some reason the database is showing multiple connections but no data is being inserted. I do have one active connection from Visual Studio to this database, I am not sure if that is denying more connection

Comment: In the error you get (I'm assuming on the `TableOperationCallback<E>`'s `onCompleted` operation), if you look at the properties of the `response` parameter, what does it say? What is its status code and what is its content?

Comment: Response is null, I tried to log it and it returned null?

Comment: Thanks, I have added the error screen shot, I have to call response.getContent(), to get the error message

Comment: Are there any inner exceptions (causes) for the error? Check out https://gist.github.com/carlosfigueira/d5e25575af38fddfb396 to see how they can be printed...

Comment: Yes, here is the actual exception, something about the hostname https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/15447938/ZUMO_Error.JPG

Comment: Thanks Carlos, I have verified that I have uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally got this to work after many frustrating hours. First it was the Starbucks wifi connection that  was somehow blocking connectivity to Azure Mobile Service. I got around this by using my phone instead of an Emulator to test. Then there is the challenge of figuring out what is the exact Table name that the ZUMO service expects.

I am using the .Net backend and created my database using EF Code first migration like so

> public DbSet(Bill) Bills { get; set; }

Given this context, when I publish to ZUMO a database table named Bills was created like so
[image: Table Name Azure Mobile Service]

So I guessed (wrongly) that the table name I should be calling from my Android client is "Bills" , turned out that for some reason Azure Mobile sees the table name as "Bill" which was the model class that was used to create the Entity Framework context. I realized this using the Web Try it out

[image: Azure Mobile Service Try it out]

So proceed cautiously with the .Net backend for Azure Mobile service, it seems to have a few gotchas to watch out for.

Comment: You're correct - in the .NET backend the "mobile service tables" don't necessarily need to be the same as the "database tables" - they're based on the name of your controller class. If you want to have the same name, you can rename your class from `BillController` to `BillsController`.